# Accessing the desktop API from a Universal Windows App to use a scanner

Tags: windows, uwp, universal

I want to be able to scan a document with my universal windows app.The problem is that The Windows.Devices.Scanners APIs are part of the desktop device family.

Is there any way to check if the app is running on a desktop, and use these API's in that case?

Any other solutions or ideas would be welcome

Comment: Use [the ApiInformation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.aspx) to see whether the class you want to use is present. There is [a sample on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/VersionAdaptiveCode).

Comment: Looks very nice, thank you !